# In Mule, How would I create an Array using MEL to be passed into a Java component

Tags: java, mule

I am Trying to Use a Java component which has 3 string parameters,

I believe to get the reflection entry point resolver to work for this I need to set the payload to be an array of 3 strings however I am struggling to find how to do this,

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

I am wanting to pass in an xml template file location,  xml xpath and new value for the node which the xpath is returning(these will be Hardcoded as array items of the payload(I assume this is the correct approach but I cannot see how to do this)):

```
    public class XMLParserWithParameters
{
    public static Object parse2(String TemplatePath, String XPathQuery, String NewValue) throws Exception
    {
```

Comment: could you share your code ?, I need more details to help you.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code in there. Don't forget to use code block so that the formatting won't mess up.

By the way, looking at your code, it's still hard to know what exactly you are trying to achieve and what is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create an array, just call the static method from MEL:

```
#[your.package.XMLParserWithParameters.parse2('a','b','c')]
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will do the job...just need to decide which answer to accept since I think all of them would do what is needed!

Comment: Why don't you pick the most straightforward one :)

Answer (score 1):

From your post I guess you are looking for a way to set a String array as payload in the config file.

Try the following way

```
 <set-payload value="#[new String[]{&quot;String1&quot; , &quot;String2&quot;, &quot;String3&quot;}]"></set-payload>
```

Or You can also try the following way.

```
<expression-transformer>
   <return-argument expression="new String(&quot;Test&quot;)" />
   <return-argument expression="new String(&quot;Test3&quot;)" />
   <return-argument expression="new String(&quot;Test5&quot;)" />
</expression-transformer>
```

In the expression you can use any of the Mule Expressioin Landuage expression.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the second example is pretty much what we managed to create

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this can be achieved using an expression transformer by setting multiple return values which will create an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set Array of String as Payload  simply this should work

Comment: <set-payload value="#[[&quot;abc&quot;,&quot;def&quot;]]"></set-payload>

Comment: You should edit your original post and add the code there.